# Acessing general config value in mlaravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a custom atributte in a laravel model, but this custom attribute depends on a general configuration table value, so i'm not sure what is the best way for getting the best performance out of it,

By now i have it this way

```
GetFinalPriceAttribute(){
   $includetax =General::all()->first()->istaxincluded

   if($includetax) return 1
   return 0.5
}
```

So my question is how can i make it to not do the general query for all models

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your configuration table is set, you can create a Configuration model, and use the [facade](http://laravel.com/docs/facades)  to refer it in a easy way.

When you instantiate the class in your service provider, you load all config that in it .

When you want to get a parameter, you would do something like :

```
MyConfig::get('istaxincluded');
```

In your MyConfig class you would have a get function like :

```
function get($param){
   if(isset($this->config['param']){
   return $this->config['param'];
}
```

}

In any controller, you can do :

```
use MyConfig; 
...
MyConfig::get($parameter);
```

Let me know if you need further help setting it up

Comment: I'm a bit confused, since I'm really new to laravel :) what is my service provider? And shoul i fetch the info in the __constructor of config model?

Comment: Read more about Laravel facade, i gave you a link there. With that, you will have a ServiceProvider.php file, where you register all your providers ( like MyConfig class ) . MyConfig is just an eloquent model. In your constructor, you will load all data once, and set them in a class property, say it $config. In your service provider, you will instantiate the class once, and that instance will be use across the application.

Comment: Ok it makes more sense thanks! And it will be done for each request right? I mean if different users load the page the will get their different config right?

Comment: i'm not sure at what you are referring to. The config will load once / each page request, it's similar concept as a singleton . If different models in your application will request different configurations, MyConfig  class will load the configurations only once ( in the constructor )

Comment: Using Laravel Facades it's way easier to refer to in all your application ( you simply put the use MyConfig; ). Laravel Facades is also considered to be a best practice method, because, for example, you want to replace your MyConfig implementation, with another class ( that, for example, uses files for extracting the config data ), then you would simply replace the line where you load the class in your service provider. If you would use singleton, then you would have to replace all classes that use this Config.

Comment: I see ok! So the idea is have the config model class, the have the facade claa and finally register into service provider right?

Comment: exactly ! check here a good example : http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4